# stack around variable is corrupted. C visual studio

Tags: c

I am making a program to convert weight and height from metric to US and vice versa. I did the height part successfully, but the part with the weight is giving me a runtime error that stack around variable was corrupted.

I know that happens with arrays because pretty much thats all I get when I google the issue, but this is happening with a regular integer variable in 2 different functions.

This is the function that calls other functions to convert weight, one is for input, one is to convert and one is for output:

```
void weight_to_metric(void){

    int kilograms, pounds;

    double grams, ounces; 

    int * pkilograms= &kilograms, *ppounds=&pounds;

    double * pgrams=&grams, *pounces=&ounces;


    input_us_weight(ppounds, pounces);

    weight_us_to_metric(ppounds, pounces, pkilograms, pgrams);

    output_metric_weight(pkilograms, pgrams);

}
```

this is the function that inputs

```
void input_us_weight(int* feet, double * inches){
    printf("enter the number of pounds you want to convert: ");

    scanf(" %lf", feet, "\n");

    printf("enter the number of ounces you want to convert: ");

    scanf(" %lf", inches, "\n");

}
```

this is the function that converts

```
void weight_us_to_metric(int* pounds, double* ounces, int* kilograms, double * grams){

    double temp_kilograms;
    *kilograms = *pounds / 2.2046 + ((*ounces / 16) / 2.2046);

    temp_kilograms = *pounds / 2.2046 + ((*ounces / 16) / 2.2046);
    *ounces = ((temp_kilograms - *kilograms) *2.2046)*16;

    *grams = ((*ounces / 16.0)/2.2046) * 1000;
}
```

The output function doesn't even deal with the variable that corrupts. The variable that corrupts is pounds. The integer pounds declared in the initial variable.

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You are using wrong format specifiers in one of your `scanf`s. Use `%d` when scanning an `int` and `%lf` when scanning a `double`. Change

```
scanf(" %lf", feet, "\n");
```

to

```
scanf("%d", feet);
```

Also, remove the third argument(`"\n"`) that you pass to the `scanf`s. It makes no sense.